# Fibonacci retracement for stock timeseries data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, fibonacci

I can't find a solution to the following problem. 
Given a dataframe with columns `['Open', 'High', 'Low', Close']`, I would like to have other columns with fibonacci levels given an N look back period.

pseudo code as follow:

```
look_back_period = 895
maxr = highest(close, look_back_period)
minr = lowest(close, look_back_period)
ranr = maxr - minr

ON = maxr
SS = maxr - 0.236 * ranr
SO = maxr - 0.382 * ranr
FI = maxr - 0.50 * ranr
TE = minr + 0.382 * ranr
TT = minr + 0.236 * ranr
ZZ = minr
```

I would like to have the above column with the relavitive number. That changes only when `minr` or `maxr` changes.

Hope it was clear enough.

Comment: Hey buddy, welcome to SO, have a read of [ask] and if possible - post some sample (or real) data and your intended output.

Answer (score 2):

Given you have your data already in a pandas dataframe called `df` you're able to get your wanted functionality with the pandas `apply` method:

```
lookBack = 895
def minFunction(row):
    if row.name < lookBack:
        return 0
    return df['Close'].loc[row.name - lookBack:row.name].min()

df['minr'] = df.apply(minFunction, axis = 1)
```

You can continue implementing the `maxFunction` in the same way.
I hope this answer helps you solving your problem.

Comment: this would be good for one. 
But I would like to have a totally new column with fibonacci, that changes only if in the previous look_back_period, there is a higher number for maxr, or lower number for minr.

Comment: Ah sorry, I din't get that. I edited my answer, it should fit to your question now ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is how a resolved. Don't know if it is the most efficient way but felt like sharing it.

```
look_back_period = 895

c = 0 

ON = []
SS = []
TT = []
ZZ = [] 


for i in df['Close']:
    if c + look_back_period < len(df): 
        df2 = df.iloc[c : c + look_back_period, : ]
        maxr = df2['Close'].max()
        minr = df2['Close'].min()
        ranr = maxr - minr 

        ON.append(maxr)
        SS.append(maxr - 0.236 * ranr)
        TT.append(minr + 0.236 * ranr)
        ZZ.append(minr)
        c = c + 1
    else: 
        break 



df = df.head(-895)
df['ON'] = ON 
df['SS'] = SS
df['TT'] = TT
df['ZZ'] = ZZ

df = df.to_csv('5_min_fibonacci_values.csv', index=False)
```